# React debug in browser when using bundle.js

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, webpack

Tools: Chrome Developer Tools, ReactJs and Webpack

Maybe it was when I switched to bundling with webpack, but initially when I started my project I was able to bundle my js into a bundle.js file but still have access to the files in the browser debugging tool. Now all I see in the browser in my js folder is bundle.js

Using webpack how do I get back to being able to see all my Javascript files in the browser debugger so I can do stuff like insert breakpoints?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a long time of pointlessly using a bunch of print statements I finally went back and figured out how to do this.

**Here is how you get your ability to use breakpoints again after you bundle:**

**1)**

Go to your webpack.config.js file and set devtools from "true" to "source-map" or one of the other options that @MichelleTilley explained in her answer.

webpack.config.js(here is an example)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**2)**

Also like @MichelleTilley explained in her answer you may need to enable the devtools options in the Chrome.

**3)**

After this the when you go to debug you will have to look for a new folder just named "." that is super hard to notice!

Thanks to the Stackoverflow answer below with the posted images I finally found where that folder was.

[Configure webpack to allow browser debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging)

Comment: Can anybody tell which "devtools options in the Chrome" to enable to make this work? I got it working in FireFox, but in Chrome, I can see the javascript in clear text, but my break point doesn't stop. In Firefox, the bundled scripts are so cluttered, so I like Chrome's way to show them in folders, but I have to make it work first.

Comment: Ah, I see "enable JavaScript source map" and "enable CSS source map" in Chrome devtools now and both are checked by default. Interestingly, after some playaround, chrome is now working too. go figure.

Comment: "   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.0.0." See newer answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [the `devtool` option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) to have webpack generate source maps, which ([when enabled in the Chrome devtools options](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings)) will allow Chrome to translate the code in `bundle.js` (which may even be minified) into the original source code.

For development, I set this option to `eval-source-map` or `cheap-eval-source-map`, and for production I either leave this off or generate separate source map files with `source-map`.

Comment: I remember someone highly recommending "source maps" I'm gonna try it out and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I added these to my webpack.config.js file                                                    debug: true,
devtool: "#eval-source-map",                                                                                  and in the dev tools source maps is enabled for js but I still only see the bundle.js

Answer (score 6):

Its updated now you have to just include mode:"development" in top of module.exports and set a debugger in any where in your .js file it will work and open chrome devtools
webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
entry: path.join(__dirname,'src/js','index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'build.js'
   },
  module: {}
}
```

[check](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/)

Comment: "check" link is a 404... looks like the "mode" property is no longer valid sytax...

Comment: @Andrew what is the valid way to do it now? Is source maps enough? I never tried them, I know they help to trace back the real origin of error, but what I'm looking for is to be able to debug bundle.js file in Chrome or at least have access to src files in the browser and not just minified bundle.js

Comment: The link works now, so I retract my earlier statement.  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/. Seems to be the way to go.