# Google chrome logs indicating xml.js:30 instead of actual line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, javascript-debugger

I'm using react v15.6.1 and webpack v1.13.1 and bundle my stuff to a file and it's usually no problem. But now for the last hours or so whenever I get an error or just log something and look at the console in google chrome every log and error is said to come from row 30 in xml.js, which is a file I haven't even created myself. Testing it out on Firefox it all works normally but not in chrome for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a source map to your webpack bundle config.

*webpack.dev.config.js*:

```
const config = {

    devtool: 'source-map',

    ..
}
```

See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool

Related question: [React debug in browser when using bundle.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826375/react-debug-in-browser-when-using-bundle-js)