# chrome developer tool show only bundle.js instead normal components js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i'm using react and when i want to use debugger in my code adn see it via chrome  it shows me only bundle.js in sources tab. How do i fix it. On my friends pc its looks normal on the same project. tried to check chrome options bun didnt fine anything usefull. at google i find only people with webpack but i didnt use it  [image: Here how it looks like when i type debugger]

Comment: React uses webpack even without your will, look at the answer here and fix it for you too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826375/react-debug-in-browser-when-using-bundle-js

Comment: 1) You _do_ use webpack (through react probably), as you can see on the top of your screenshot. 2) If you don't see source maps then either you have bundled your code in production mode, or you have source maps disabled in your Devtools settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CherryDT. it happend becausesource maps disabled in your Devtools settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the exact place to enable this flag:
[image]

I had the same issue and it fixed it for me