# How to find the file where my React/Redux error is coming from?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm using webpack to compile my React/Redux app. It's throwing an error on screen in the browser (red screen), but not in the console. Is there a way to configure webpack to point to the exact component/container (file) where it's running into this error?

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: bindActionCreators expected an object or a function, instead received undefined. Did you write "import ActionCreators from" instead of "import * as ActionCreators from"?

bindActionCreators
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:4049:2

mapDispatchToProps
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:1129:2

ProxyComponent.configureFinalMapDispatch
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3381:2

ProxyComponent.configureFinalMapDispatch
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3025:2

ProxyComponent.computeDispatchProps
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3381:2

ProxyComponent.computeDispatchProps
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3025:2

ProxyComponent.updateDispatchPropsIfNeeded
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3381:2

ProxyComponent.updateDispatchPropsIfNeeded
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3025:2

ProxyComponent.render
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3381:2

ProxyComponent.render
http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js:3025:2
```

Here is my **webpack.dev.config.js** file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    children: false,
    assets: false,
  },
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'client', 'index.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js|jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'client'),
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'client'),
      loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:8]!postcss',
      ],
    },
    {
      test: /\.jpe?g|jpg|gif|svg|png$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf|woff|woff2|eot$/,
      loader: 'file',
    }],
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [
      require('postcss-import'),
      require('postcss-constants')({
        defaults: Object.assign({},
          require('../src/styles/_globals/colors')),
      }),
      require('postcss-mixins'),
      require('postcss-nested'),
      require('postcss-cssnext')
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify({
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      }),
      __DEV__: true,
      __PROD__: false,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Thanks for any and all help, appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help you? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging

Comment: bindActionCreators(actions) is a function in redux which requires a object or a function in its parameter, like actions that i have passes., but in your case its null. So check it

Comment: As Gimby suggested you may need to change your `devtool` settings, since `eval-source-map` will not give you a good reference to the file your error is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change your webpack line:

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
```

into for example:

```
devtool: 'eval'
```

It will generate the sourcemaps of every file, so you can see where does the error come from.

You can learn more about source maps in webpack [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool)

Comment: I am able to generate source maps but how do I navigate to the original file from the error file mentioned by React? If I click on the file path shown by React (which is not in the console but rather in white text with red background in webpage), it opens the compiled JS file.