# React- Webpack minifying code and creating bundle in dev env. I want all unbundled files in dev so that i can debug

Tags: reactjs, webpack

React- Webpack minifying code and creating bundle in dev env. I want all unbundled files in dev so that i can debug ?

Attached below is webpack.config.js
     devServer: {
      contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
      //   port: 9001,
      compress: true,
      hot: true,
      open: true
    },

Please let me know which configurations should i be changing?

Comment: Code : https://codepen.io/Abhiseksubham/pen/PXKpJO?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of WebPack is to bundle JavaScript files.

If you want to debug the js code, try to generate sourcemap files using [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option.

If you are using webpack version 4 and above, then try to set the [mode](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) option to "[development](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/)".

The sourcemap files will be helpful while debugging in browser.

Similar discussion on another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging)