# Not hitting button debugger when onClick of Submit, but hitting it with each onChange of Form

Tags: reactjs

In the chrome dev tools I have a breakpoint set at my button for submitting the form. When I type in my input fields, each keystroke triggers the handleSubmit breakpoint and updates the state correctly onChange and also enables the Submit button under the correct circumstances, but when I actually click Submit, nothing happens. It doesn't trigger the breakpoint or run handleSubmit. I don't get errors in my server or console.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

class BoardGameForm extends Component {

  state = { title: "", 
            max_players: "", 
            min_players: "", 
            game_company: "", 
            time_needed: "",
          }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const { title,
            min_players, 
            max_players, 
            game_company, 
            time_needed 
          } = this.state 
    if (this.canBeSubmitted) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      axios.post("/api/board_games", {
        title, 
        min_players,
        max_players,
        game_company,
        time_needed
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res); 
      })
      return; 
    }
  }


  canBeSubmitted = () => {
   const {title, max_players, min_players, time_needed } = this.state; 
    return(
        title.length > 0 &&
        max_players.length > 0 &&
        min_players.length > 0 &&
        time_needed.length > 0 
    );
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target 
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }


  render() {
  const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted() 
  const {title, max_players, min_players, game_company, time_needed } = this.state 
    return (
      <Container > 
        <Form>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Title</label>
            <Form.Input 
              name="title"
              value={title} 
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            /> 
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Group widths="equal">
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Min Players</label>
              <Form.Input 
                name="min_players"
                value={min_players}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Max Players</label>
              <Form.Input 
                name="max_players"
                value={max_players}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required 
              /> 
            </Form.Field>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Game Company</label>
            <Form.Input 
              name="game_company"
              value={game_company}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Time Needed</label>
            <Form.Input 
              name="time_needed"
              value={time_needed}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            /> 
          </Form.Field>
        </Form>
        <Button disabled={!isEnabled} onClick={() => this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { user: state.user };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BoardGameForm);
```

Comment: Looks like issue with webpack sourcemap. Possible solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this issue because you are not calling a function.

Code should be

```
<Button disabled={!isEnabled} onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Submit</Button>
```

or even simpler

```
<Button disabled={!isEnabled} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

because this was already bound to context.

If you would prefer more ideological solution you may need to do 2 modifications in your code:

1. Replace `<Form>` with `<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`
2. Add `type="submit"` to the `<Button>` component instead of `onClick`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I made the 2 modifications, but it still isn't working. I'm not getting a response in my console or anything in my servers.

Comment: Have you tried the first option `onClick={this.handleSubmit}`? As `semantic-ui-react` may have specific API

Comment: It ultimately ended up working with the button set up like so:        <Button disabled={!isEnabled} type="submit" onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</Button>

Comment: Cool, that what I have suggested as option 1. Also I have made a working example, check it https://codesandbox.io/s/zwr8rr9pol