# Objects called in browser after webpack bundle show undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I am new to webpack and I want to debug using console.log in my browser and by calling functions to see what works, but whenever I try to do this after my js files are bundled everything shows up as undefined. Webpack must be changing the names somehow when the files get bundled together so even if I make a simple let x = 'hello', I can't console.log it and I can't even call any functions I made without them being undefined when I use them in the console.

How can I fix this so that I can call the objects that I made in the console? Here is my simple webpack config- 
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
      app:'./src/js/index.js',
      test:'./src/js/test2.js',
      create: './src/js/create.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map ',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      compress: true,
      port: 8080,
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'Menu',
          template: './src/views/index.ejs',
      })
    ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
          {
           test: /\.scss$/,
           use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsnpm$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', {
              'debug':true
            }]
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
           use: [
           'file-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
   },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/contribute/debugging/
This would be helpful for getting in depth of debugging webpacks! good documentation for debugging webpacks.
In case you want to use browser for debugging, this may be helpful:
[Configure webpack to allow browser debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging)

Hope this helps!