# What method does webpack use to show the sources in a 'webpack://' folder in dev tools?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, source-maps

If I use webpack in dev mode, when I open chrome dev tools, in the 'sources' tab, I can see a 'webpack://' folder with all my source code.

[image]

I would like to know how I could do something similar with my own code (without webpack).

Let's say that I want to program my own build system. This build system takes some source code then transpiles it. How can I show the original source code (including js, html, and css files) in a special folder (for example 'mysource://')?

Comment: please check this post (i can not comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626764/configure-webpack-to-allow-browser-debugging

Answer (score 3):

The source code you see in your DevTool-window are so called 'source-maps', in webpack they are generated (in most cases) by the [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/)
 by default when in 'dev' mode.

[Here](https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/source-maps/#-sourcemapdevtoolplugin-and-evalsourcemapdevtoolplugin-) is another article about how to generate source maps.